# Where could I find/download/install Ubuntu application software?

Tags: software-center, software-sources, evolution, find

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, and found that there are fewer applications in Software Center, for example, I could not find Evolution for email.

Is there any other way that I could obtain Ubuntu application other than using the Software Center, and download / install them?

Comment: Thanks @Zanna for editing the post. Yes it was a duplicated question. Sorry for this.

Comment: No problem :) duplicate posts often help future visitors find the answer by adding more links to it

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the wiki for further documentation onto how the main repositories work: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

The location of these settings may vary dependent on your flavor of Ubuntu and desktop. It is recommended that you install Synaptic via the Software Center or via aptitude (sudo apt-get install synaptic) after enabling the "Universe" repository.

Enabling the "Universe" repository will allow you to install third party open source software which includes the Evolution email client and Synaptic.

If you are not using these repositories on purpose, you may be missing out on updates and dependencies via the repositories. The direct deb downloads for Evolution can be found here: https://pkgs.org/download/evolution

Select your Ubuntu version and either select the Ubuntu Universe amd64 package (For 64bit Computers) or the Ubuntu Universe i386 package (For 32bit Computers)

Answer (score 2):

Synaptic Package Manager should be a good choice for you to find packages.

To download Synaptic Package Manager, open a terminal and type `apt-get install synaptic` with root access.

---

Another thing is, the default Ubuntu repository does not include all softwares you want, e.g. for Evolution, you have to add the gnome PPA into your apt source list before you can download it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fta/gnome3  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

This can help you install Evolution in Ubuntu.

You have to manually add the software's PPA before Ubuntu can find the package (and they will never show up in Ubuntu Software Center).

---

If they do not offer PPAs, possibly you can download a .deb package and install it with `dpkg -i`. Or, if they only offer source code, you have to compile it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I did installation with following responses from the system: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: your system is only accepting the software as per 
@Cynplytholowazy comment.  most likely only 'main' or software with full five years support (by Canonical) & those available on original cd/install-media.   lots of additional software is available when you enable 'restricted', 'universe', 'multiverse' which contain non-free (binaries only etc) or community supported (& not Canonical supported).  I too use Evolution  :)  In 'Ubuntu Software' you can select 'Software & Updates' and then you'll see the tick-boxes needed...

Comment: thanks @guiverc, enabled others and all issues addressed!